# Replace C++ class/static method with preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++17, c-preprocessor

I'd like to use the built-in compiler checks to verify format strings of a custom logging framework to catch the odd runtime crash due to mismatching format string <-> parameters in advance.

Arguments of the custom C++ logging methods are identical to the `printf()` family so I was attempting to replace all calls to

```
MyLogger::Error(
```

with

```
fprintf(stderr,
```

Though unfortunately the (clang) preprocessor chokes on the scope resolution operator (`::`), i.e. instead of `ULog::Warn(` only the `ULog` substring is recognized:

```
#define MyLogger::Error( fprintf(stderr,
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work much appreciated.

Comment: Colons aren't allowed in preprocessor macros. Have you considered using a `constexpr` function? They're executed at compile time, and you get the full power of the language without preprocessor limitations.

Comment: If you use GCC or Clang then you could add function attributes to check `printf` like strings and their arguments Search for e.g. `gcc attribute printf`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure how I've never heard of that before. Good one.

Comment: @3Dave Not yet, I'll have to look into that - cheers!

Comment: Why not use `sed`? `sed "s/MyLogger::Error(/fprintf(stderr,/" < source.cpp > source_modified.cpp`

Comment: Note: a portable way of doing this is using the C++ attribute syntax which should be ignored on other platforms ex: `[[gnu::format (printf, 1, 2)]]` [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7en7xc9qe)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Love gcc attributes, totally solves what I was trying to achieve - even better, it's enabled all the time (not just for test runs)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on the approach suggested by *@Someprogrammerdude* I've extended the custom logging class to use the clang/gcc **format** attribute to enable compiler format checking.

The declaration simply becomes

```
static void     Error(const char *format,...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));
```

It's even better than the original idea to use the preprocessor to temp. enable checks by replacing calls to the custom formatter with calls to `printf()` as it's enabled all the time catching argument mismatches immediately!

(FWIW - already fixed dozens of issues and couple potential crashes on our 120+ LOC code base)

Comment: 120+ LOC, doesn't seem that much.

Comment: LOL - supposed to say 120k ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a variadic template? found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ead1GGje6).

```
#include <iostream>

namespace MyLogger
{
    template <typename... T> 
    auto Error(const char * _Format, T &&... args) 
    { 
        return printf(_Format, std::forward<T>(args)...); 
    };
}

#define printf(...) MyLogger::Error(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() 
{
    MyLogger::Error("Non-Macro Print \n");
    printf("Macro Print \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What if you modify `MyLogger::Error` to

```
MyLogger::Error(args){
    if (0) {
        fprintf(stderr,args)
    }
    //actual function
}
```

This way you get the built-in warnings and it does not effect the efficiency of your code. (You can obviosly actually use the print if you wan to write to stderr, but I think if you wanted that you used that already)

Comment: The problem is that the format string is variable in this function body, so you won't get built-in warnings

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right.